# No theme files found in LAN in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

i am having a problem with my Wordpress instalation when i try to see my localhost in other computer inside the same network with the ip 192.168.1.201.

For example the code resolves in both browsers as:

And the PC in the network that don´t have those files in localhost, it doesn´t load the resources.

How can i fix this to both in internal LAN? Any kind of redirect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question. If you want to browse your localhost site from other computers on same IP, you should use

```
http://yourcomputername/wordpress_site/
```

"yourcomputername" is where you installed the wamp / xampp

Also You should have to change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to

```
http://yourcomputername/wordpress_site/
```

In wordpress Settings > General

```
http://localhost
```

will only work on the computer where you installed wamp